# Can I know which key has pressed when application did enter background?

Tags: ios, lifecycle

Can I know which key has pressed when application did enter background? "Home" button or "On/Off" button.

Comment: update: In the method - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are a variety of reasons your application can enter background, but you just know that the state has changed.

Without using private APIs, there is no way to know for sure. In addition to the user pressing a button, your application can enter the background for auto-lock events, for example, so even the assumption that a button was pressed may be wrong.